# character only turns while mouse is over the game

Tags: python, pygame

When I run the code to my menu everything seems to work fine except my "screen.blit(presentskin, (270, 400))". This part of the code only works when my mouse is over the pygame window. The code is supposed to flip the image on the screen over and over. But the image only starts flipping when my mouse is over the game window.

```py
while menu:
    clock.tick(60)
    if game_over == 2: #game menu
        start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        screen.blit(bgmenu, (0, 0)) #draw background

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        start_buttons(presentskin)
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #gets the mouse postion
        screen.blit(arrow_left, (200, 440))
        screen.blit(arrow_right, (330, 440))
        screen.blit(arrow_left, (170, 740))
        screen.blit(arrow_right, (360, 740))

        if skin == 14:
            skin = 1
        if skin == 0:
            skin = 13
        if skin == 16 or skin == 18:
            skin = 1





        for event in pygame.event.get():


            if mx >= 600 and mx <= 850 and my >= 0 and my <= 20 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: #gets x and y of mouse to check if it is on the button
                skin = 17
                music = pygame.mixer.music.load(f'newgameimg/sounds/music10.wav')
                pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
                if mutee == 1:
                    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                elif mutee == 0:
                    pygame.mixer.music.pause()







            if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]: #game quit
                menu = False
            if mx >= 225 and mx <= 445 and my >= 250 and my <= 350 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: #gets x and y of mouse to check if it is on the button

                #this code starts the game

                score = 0
                speedcost = 10
                speeds = 1
                coffeecost = 10
                coffees = 1
                coffeefallspeed = 2.5
                speed = playerspeed
                y = 595
                x = 25
                xx = random.randrange(50, 600)
                xy = random.randrange(-300, -100)
                anvilx = random.randrange(50, 600)
                anvily = random.randrange(-300, -100)
                coffeeaddspeed = 1

                #spawns the clouds

                cloudx = []
                cloudy = []
                cloudimage = []
                cloudx_change = []
                for i in range(num_of_clouds):
                    cloudimage.append(pygame.image.load("newgameimg/bg/cloud.png"))
                    cloudx.append(random.randrange(-200, 700))
                    cloudy.append(random.randrange(10, 300))
                    cloudx_change.append(1)



                game_over = 0
                enemyx = 998
                enemyspeedup = 0
                isJump = False
                coffeeimage = []
                coffeex = []
                coffeey = []
                coffeey_change = []
                num_of_coffee = 1
                for i in range(num_of_coffee):
                    coffeeimage.append(pygame.image.load("newgameimg/coffee/coffee_bean1.png"))
                    coffeex.append(random.randrange(0, 600))
                    coffeey.append(random.randrange(-250, -45))
                    coffeey_change.append(coffeefallspeed)




            if mx >= 480 and mx <= 633 and my >= 720 and my <= 785 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: #quit button
                menu = False
            if mx >= 65 and mx <= 109 and my >= 739 and my <= 788 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP or keys[pygame.K_m]: #this is for muting the game music
                if mutee == 1:
                    mutee = 0
                    muteorunmute = mutepng
                    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                elif mutee == 0:
                    mutee = 1
                    muteorunmute = unmutepng
                    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
            if mx >= 245 and mx <= 263 and my >= 442 and my <= 477 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP or keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]: #changes skin
                skin = skin - 1
            if skin < 1:
                skin = 13

            if mx >= 367 and mx <= 394 and my >= 442 and my <= 477 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]: #changes skin
                skin = skin + 1
                if skin > 13:
                    skin = 1

                #song changer
            if mx >= 405 and mx <= 421 and my >= 742 and my <= 777 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: #music chooser
                song += 1
                if song == 6:
                    song = 1
                music = pygame.mixer.music.load(f'newgameimg/sounds/music{song}.wav')
                pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

            if mx >= 215 and mx <= 234 and my >= 742 and my <= 777 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: #music chooser
                song -= 1
                if song == 0:
                    song = 4
                music = pygame.mixer.music.load(f'newgameimg/sounds/music{song}.wav')
                pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

            playerturn += 1
            if playerturn <= 50:
                presentskin = pygame.image.load(f'newgameimg/players/main{skin}.png')
            elif playerturn >= 50:
                leftskin = pygame.image.load(f'newgameimg/players/main{skin}.png')
                presentskin = pygame.transform.flip(leftskin, True, False)
            if playerturn >= 100:
                playerturn = 0

            screen.blit(presentskin, (270, 400))
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: well if You make it fullscreen the mouse will be on top always (unless exiting the fullscreen mode)

Comment: `screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, FULLSCREEN|SCALED)` to make it fill the entire screen. You can also add a key (F11 or Escape) to switch between normal size when you are testing the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to call `screen.blit(presentskin, (270, 400))` in the application loop instead of the event loop:

```py
while menu:
    clock.tick(60)
    if game_over == 2: #game menu
        # [...]

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # [...] 

 
        # INDENTATION
        #<--|
        screen.blit(presentskin, (270, 400))
 
        pygame.display.update()
```